# Error: No module named staticfiles

Tags: python, django, deployment, nginx

I'm newbie with django, I'm trying to deploy my project on a production server but I'm getting this error:

```
Error: No module named staticfiles
```

When trying to start the server:

```
python manage.py runfcgi host=127.0.0.1 port=8081 --settings=settings
```

with the fastCGI + nginx

Any idea?

Thanks!

Comment: Adding a bit of traceback from the server's error log would be helpful.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I just remove the whole server and installed everything again, that solved everything. Seems I got some old django ghost installation or something

Sorry and thanks!

Answer (score 30):

You're probably using older version of Django. staticfiles app has been available from version 1.3 only.

Comment: I have just downloaded the last version from the trunk. I'll check that anyway

Comment: Type "help", "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information.
>>> import django
>>> django.VERSION
(1, 3, 0, 'alpha', 0)

Comment: Thanks for this answer, you just saved me a major headache digging into this issue.

Answer (score 6):

You most likely need to upgrade your version of django by using setuptools

```
sudo easy_install --upgrade django
```

Answer (score 3):

FYI - I just ran into this error. The default Django for the system is 1.2.1 and I am using Django 1.3 in a virtualenv. I was getting the error because I had forgotten to activate my virtualenv so it was trying to use the system Django.

Answer (score 3):

Another way this error could occur; is that you call `./manage.py` even if your in the correct virtualenv. For some reason it uses the system python as supposed to the virtualenv one.

The correct syntax is:

```
python manage.py <command>
```

I hope this saves someone some time.