# Why am i getting the following error in python "No module named static files"?

Tags: python, django

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Error: No module named staticfiles](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4987333/error-no-module-named-staticfiles)

My project path is:-
/home/jayesh/Myproject/mysite/.

So when i am trying to run the project using "python manage.py runserver" command in mysite directory i am getting the error named "No module named staticfiles"

So plz if anyone can help me with this.

Comment: You don't have `staticfiles` or you are using django < 1.3. How can we know what the problem is without telling us your Django version, server setup, relevant settings, etc.

Comment: i am using django version 1.3.1 & i have installed django on default system path.

Answer (score 0):

Just install the latest version. That way, the tutorials will work and you will have the newest features.

Comment: Thanks for ur help everyone ...
after installing newer version my project started running.